# How to add shell scripts to the war file generated by maven

Tags: shell, war

I have created a webservice that talks to a shell script. I created a war file and deployed on the tomcat server. The java classes are there but the shell scripts are not there.

Can some one guide me how to add the shell scripts to the war file

Note: I tried to manually add the war files after the war was deployed but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The default resource directory for all Maven projects is src/main/resources which will end up in target/classes and in WEB-INF/classes in the WAR. Place your shell scripts in src/main/resources

Comment: Thank you for the useful solution. How do I put the path of the shell script in the webservice now?

Comment: @user3627332 that is a different issue and it depends on the environment where the web service will be deployed, you should either check with the administrator of the server or learn about the operating system running in the server